# Prevent application parts from beign copied to the output directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I've split my ASP.NET Core application into multiple projects using the [Application Parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-7.0) feature. One of them is where I manage my communication UI. Within that project, I've got the extension method below, which I use to include the shared communication content in my main project,

```cs
public static IMvcBuilder AddCommunicationUI(this IMvcBuilder builder)
{
    builder.AddApplicationPart(typeof(ServiceCollectionExtensions).Assembly);
    builder.Services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(ServiceCollectionExtensions).Assembly));
    });

    return builder;
}
```

My problem is that when published, all `cshtml` files content from the communication project are being copied to output directory.
Is there any way of preventing that kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion as below:

If you don't want to publish some files, you need to set  in csproj file.Sample to prevent files from being published like :

```
  <ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot\data\file.json">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: `cshtml` files default to "Do not copy". Yet, I tried to explicitly set `CopyToPublishDirectory` to `Never` but, that didn't work as well.